# CSS - Z-index is not working with positions relative and absolute

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've made dropdown menu using pure css3, but one property(z-index) is not working as I expected and that is a very big problem, because the dropdown list is dropping ABOVE the menu. Ideally it must be dropped UNDER the menu. I've tried to do something with that problem all day but unfortunately can't figure it out, so now asking for help...
I've made a different background-colors for problem items for good seeing what i'm trying to reach. The main aim is that sub-menu with red background must be under the blue background.

P.S. I've already tried to make this menu with jQuery slideDown/slideUp properties but they don't look like ideal slide effect(as in my example). They look more like stretching, and that's not what I want..

[EXAMPLE ON JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bwxpmgv3/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  /* IS NOT WORKING... O_o...*/
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.menu li a {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #05487F;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /* IS NOT WORKING... O_o...*/
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -132px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.sub-menu li {
  float: none;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.menu li a:hover + .sub-menu {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.sub-menu:hover {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu_wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news/index.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">PROBLEM HERE<br>(HOVER THIS)</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Something</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're [establishing a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) on `.menu_wrapper` when you set `z-index: 999`. When a stacking context is established, you *cannot* position a descendant element behind an ancestor.

Remove `z-index: 999` from `.menu_wrapper`:

```
.menu_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 999; << remove */
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Then change the `z-index` on `.sub-menu` from `1` to a negative number such as `-1`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ttwqkLbg/)

```
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -132px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Being accurate: you establish a stacking context when you set both: `position` to `relative` or `absolute` and `z-index` to value other than `auto`

Comment: z-index: -1 is the solution

Answer (score 5):

Here is the deal with z-index.

Z-index is relative to its parent (and ultimately relative to the Window object) in the normal DOM flow. However, Absolutely positioned objects are removed from the normal DOM flow and therefore, Z-Index is relative to itself - rather than the Window object.

In your case, you have not set position for your parent menu, so it will be automatically assigned `position:static` which CANNOT be z-indexed.

Adding the following to your parent menu should allow you to z-index the submenu to rest above it.

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```